To use standard "Insert email template" in custom LWC email composer
I have created a custom LWC email composer. I want to use or mirror the standard lightning "Insert email template" functionality (screenshots attached for reference). Is there a way to use the feature in LWC as we can use LDS lightning record form? or the out of the box Email quick action.
Example: in Salesforce Contact record we have a button to send email to the contacts and in email composer we can see the Insert Email Template option at the bottom left of the model.
If anyone have any experience on this please guide me to the right direction.

Hi @hari, Welcome to SFSE ! What have you tried so far? Where did you got stuck? Can you add more details by editing your questions?

@sanketkumar: i have create the custom email composer which have similar functionality as the standard email composer. However, I am unable to find a way to use the insert template function as it is in standard out of the box email composer of SF.
